# How to run subversion without changing the current working directory (CWD)?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to perform actions such as diff, commit, cleanup .. etc. without changing the current directory?

eg:

```
cd my_subdir
svn commit . -m "My Message"
cd ..
```

Does subversion provide a way to do something like this?

```
svn commit --workdir=my_subdir . -m "My Message"
```

---

Asking because I would like to perform subversion operations without having to change the directory each time.

Comment: maybe not the answer you want but `(cd my_subdir && svn commit . -m "My Message")` should work, at least on mac, linux and bash for windows. The parenthesis are important

Comment: Have you tried: `svn commit /path/to/folder -m "message"`?